# Is there a regression metric for the order of values?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, metric

In regression methods one usually predicts a value to be as close to certain other value as possible. However, what if one wants to predict values in such a way that the order of the values are important, almost as a classification problem. One might ask if it would be better to formalize the problem as classification.

Let's say I have a test set of labels $y_{test} = [1, 10, 15]$ and we make three predictions predict $y_{train1} = [1000, 3000, 5000]$, $y_{train2} = [3, 11, 14]$, and $y_{train3} = [6, 5, 14]$.

The metric I'm interested in would score $y_{train1}$ equally well as $y_{train2}$ as they predict the right order of values as in $y_{test}$ whereas $y_{train3}$ would have a better *explained variance score* than $y_{train1}$.

Is there such a metric?

Comment: I suspect you may be looking for things like a rank correlation coefficient such as [Kendall's $\tau$ coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) or [Spearman's $\rho$ coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)